# Laravel 5.2 Mongo MonogDB Failed to parse MongoDB URI

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5

I am getting this error:

```
MongoDB\Driver\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Failed to parse MongoDB URI: 'mongodb://mongo:tcp://172.17.0.3:27017/mydatabase' in /var/www/laravel/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Client.php:81
```

My enviroment variables look like this:

```
MONGO_DATABASE="mydatabase"
MONGO_HOST="mongo"
MONGO_PASSWORD=""
MONGO_PORT="27017"
MONGO_USERNAME=""
```

and my `database.php` looks like this

```
'mongodb' => [
    'driver'   => 'mongodb',
    'host'     => env('MONGO_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port'     => env('MONGO_PORT', 27017),
    'database' => env('MONGO_DATABASE', 'mydatabase'),
    'username' => env('MONGO_USERNAME', ''),
    'password' => env('MONGO_PASSWORD', ''),
    'options' => [
        'database' => 'admin' // sets the authentication database required by mongo 3
    ]
```

I can correctly ping `mongo` from the container and it resolves to `172.17.0.3` as per the connection string. It seems as if the rest of the connection string is not getting generated correct?

I am running `Laravel 5.2` and my `package.json` has this entry

```
"mongodb/mongodb": "^1.0.0",
"jenssegers/mongodb": "3.0.*",
```

As per https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb `3.0.X` is highest compatibility for `Laravel 5.2`.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I am also getting the same error. Laravel version 5.5, Php 7.2 and MongoDB 4.0. Anyone

Comment: how you resolved it.

Comment: Read the answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation my link from Amazon ECS was passing another `MONGO_PORT` which was overriding the env set in my `.env` file.