# Failed to parse MongoDB URI: 'mongodb://'. Invalid host string in URI

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, laravel-5.5

While trying to run MongoDB 4.0 with laravel I am getting the following error

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: 
>   Failed to parse MongoDB URI: 'mongodb://'. Invalid host string in URI. in /var/www/html/valueableapp/valueable_rest_app/api_src/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Client.php:87`

I used the command `mongo` to run the mongo shell and it's working fine.
also `sudo service mongod status` and its also showing the status running.
I am not able to start my project even anyone please. here is the complete stack trace of the issues I am getting 
php artisan serve --port=8080

> Laravel development server started: http://127.0.0.1:8080
>       [Wed May 22 10:00:54 2019] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Failed to parse MongoDB URI: 'mongodb://'. Invalid host string in URI. in /var/www/html/valueable-app/valueable_rest_app/api_src/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Client.php:87
>       Stack trace:
>       #0 /var/www/html/valueable-app/valueable_rest_app/api_src/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Client.php(87): MongoDB\Driver\Manager->__construct('mongodb://', Array, Array)
>       #1 /var/www/html/valueable-app/valueable_rest_app/api_src/vendor/jenssegers/mongodb/src/Jenssegers/Mongodb/Connection.php(141): MongoDB\Client->__construct('mongodb://', Array, Array)
>       #2 /var/www/html/valueable-app/valueable_rest_app/api_src/vendor/jenssegers/mongodb/src/Jenssegers/Mongodb/Connection.php(41): Jenssegers\Mongodb\Connection->createConnection('mongodb://', Array, Array)
>       #3 /var/www/html/valueable-app/valueable_rest_app/api_src/vendor/jenssegers/mongodb/src/Jenssegers/Mongodb/MongodbServiceProvider.php(30): Jenssegers\Mongodb\Connection->__construct(Array)
>       #4 [internal function]: Jenssegers\Mongo in /var/www/html/valueable-app/valueable_rest_app/api_src/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Client.php on line 87

**Config/database.php**

```
<?php

return [
    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,
    'default'=>'mongodb',
    'connections' => array(

        'mongodb' => array(
            'driver'   => 'mongodb',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST'),
            'port'     => env('DB_PORT'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
            'options' => [
                'database' => env('DB_DATABASE')
            ]
        ),

    ),
    'migrations' => 'migrations',
    'redis' => [

        'cluster' => false,

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],

    ],

];
```

**.env**

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:q0DOPnhqUzhmMrqryyyN6SDOi6NHKh/BbmJGHw35e3E=

DB_CONNECTION=mongodb
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=27017
DB_DATABASE=abc
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=



CACHE_DRIVER=array
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

CRITERIA_MAX_SCORE=5
CRITERIA_MIN_SCORE=1
MAX_SCORE_APP=1000
```

Thanks in advance. I have look for the solution on this site
[Laravel 5.2 Mongo MonogDB Failed to parse MongoDB URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42533402/laravel-5-2-mongo-monogdb-failed-to-parse-mongodb-uri)  but this question is not having answer.

Comment: It's hard to help you without seeing your config files (like relevant sections of `config/database.php` or `.env`). Can you post them and edit your question?

Comment: I have added those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I just resolved it but changing the name of the file from `.env` to `.env.local`.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error because of a wrong port number. Kindly confirm first

Comment: You could have same error can be produced from multiple ways.

Comment: if its cant find find manager then most likely it falls to either port or path